# Excel Import - Error caused by filepath/filename

Tags: python, excel, import, filepath

I have a problem with import from Excel. Filename is something like:

```
file_location = "R:\Projects\2-current\2015-06-02 data.xlsm"
book = xlrd.open_workbook(file_location)
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(1)
```

When I run it shows the following error:

> OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: "R:\Projects\x02 -
>   current\x815-06-02 data.xlsm"

So there seems to be a problem with numbers as first character of a file/path (when I rename the file and put it directly into "R", everything works fine).

What can I do about it?

Answer (score 2):

Try `file_location = "R:\\Projects\\2-current\\2015-06-02 data.xlsm"` or `file_location = r"R:\Projects\2-current\2015-06-02 data.xlsm"`

The problem is that paths on windows require "\" that is a special char in python. You can solve similar issues using `"...\\..."` or `r"...\..."`.

Lastly, importing the os module you can use `file_location = os.path.normpath("R:/Projects/2-current/2015-06-02 data.xlsm")` using the forward slash instead the back one.

Comment: Great! Now you can upvote and sign that the answer solved you issue.

Comment: You don't even need `normpath()`. Windows' file system calls support / instead of \. It's just the command shell that needs \ because options start with /.